# How to install LyX with already installed Texlive distribution?

Tags: lyx, texlive, installing

I’m pretty new to LaTex and so on, and I would like to install LyX with my already installed, up-to-date Texlive distribution.

The issue is that when I do the following command on Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt install lyx
```

It installs LyX, but also another Texlive distribution.

What I want is to just install LyX, and make it use my Texlive distribution.

By the way I’m installing LyX from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Elyx-devel/+archive/ubuntu/release), because the LyX version coming with the Ubuntu distribution is out-of-date.

Comment: there is a stub debian texlive package that just has enough so apt packages see texlive as installed even if the real tex is the upstream texlive. There is an answer on site about that ,somewhere...

Comment: see the accepted answer here that discusses that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: you can often disable these recommended installs using `sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lyx` (`--no-install-recommends` in one word)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but this answer is about installing the vanilla Texlive and implementing it in the root system so that `apt` may see it. What I would like is rather to keep it local so that it avoids another layer of complexity within the system, and that LyX, however, still recognizes it and uses it.

Comment: my understanding is that lyx will use it if it's in the path, the apt stub though stops lyx (and other apt packages with a tex dependency) re-installing the system tex every time you update them.

Answer (score 1):

Daleif's answer in his comment above worked for me (I also use the PPA for the latest LyX):

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends lyx
```

In my case, it took some iterations with the reconfigure command in LyX (and restarting LyX), with a few `tlmgr install` of missing stuff to get my documents to work, but that's to be expected.

The Ubuntu 20.04 installs of texlive are not like the texlive recommended installs into, say, `/usr/local/texlive/2021/...`, so this solution is great.